# Docker GraphDB Container Not Starting with bind mount

Tags: docker, bind, graphdb

I am trying to bind mount a directory to a GraphDB container, but the container exits (stops) immediately. If I remove the `-v` bind mount, I don't have this issue.

Example:

`$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:7200:7200 --name graphdb-one -t ontotext/graphdb:10.2.0 -v /home/eboraks/graphdb-import:/root/graphdb-import:ro`

Output:
`GraphDB v10.2.0+sha.748abe32.`

Without the `-v` it's working fine
`$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:7200:7200 --name graphdb-one -t ontotext/graphdb:10.2.0`

System:

- Windows 10 with WSL2.
- I am running the `docker run` from WSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `-v` option somewhere between `run` and the image name, otherwise its treated as arguments to the container's entrypoint, see [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) to learn more about the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions.

So, to run GraphDB with a bind mount you need something like this:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:7200:7200 --name graphdb-one -t -v /home/eboraks/graphdb-import:/root/graphdb-import:ro ontotext/graphdb:10.2.0
```